# Div splitting up at bottom CSS/HTML

Tags: jquery, html, css, instagram

I got multiple divs with a Image at the .back and some text at the .front classes

But for some reason it always ends up looking like this at the bottom:

[image: Weird looking bottom at the page]

The div go further on the top but the text moves above the div at the top of the screen like this:

[image: weird text box wich should move a little lower into the div]

This only happens on the top/bottom of the page in the middle between these the text boxes show up exactly in the middle of the div.

(Dont look at the weird pictures its all loaded up from instagram)

HTML:

```
<div class="flip-container">
 <div class="flipper">
  <div class="front"><p>Some Text</p></div>
  <div class="back"><img src="imgsrc"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/*############################## BODY ##############################*/

@media (min-width: 1401px) {
  #bloemfies {
  -moz-column-count:    5;
  -webkit-column-count: 5;
  -ms-column-count:     5;
  column-count:         5;
  }


}
@media (max-width: 1400px) {
  #bloemfies {
  -moz-column-count:    3;
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
  -ms-column-count:     3;
  column-count:         3;
  }

}
@media (max-width: 1000px) {
  #bloemfies {
  -moz-column-count:    2;
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  -ms-column-count:     2;
  column-count:         2;
  }

}
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  #bloemfies {
  -moz-column-count:    1;
  -webkit-column-count: 1;
  -ms-column-count:     1;
  column-count:         1;
  }
  .back img{
      min-width: 480px;
  }
}

#bloemfies{
   clear: both;
}


/*Container flip*/
/* entire container, keeps perspective */
.flip-container{
  /* Just in case there are inline attributes */
  margin-left: 0.5em;
  margin-right: 0.5em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  background-color: rgba(226, 223, 223, 1);
  min-height: 120px;
}
.flip-container, .front, .back {

}

/* flip speed goes here */
.flipper {
        position: relative;
}

/* hide back of pane during swap */
.front, .back {
        backface-visibility: hidden;
        transition: 0.8s;
        transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

/*  UPDATED! front pane, placed above back */
.back {
        z-index: 2;
        transform: rotateY(0deg);
        height: 90%;
}

/* back, initially hidden pane */
.front {
        transform: rotateY(180deg);
        position:absolute;
        overflow: auto;
        word-break: normal;
        height: 89%;
        width: 89%;
        line-height: 1.2;
        color: black;
}

.back img{
        max-width: 90%;
        height: auto;
        margin: 1em;
        overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

give .back position:absolute. it will be placed above hash tag div (.front)

```
.back{
   position:absolute;
   z-index: 2;
   transform: rotateY(0deg);
   height: 90%;
}
```

Comment: i'm a little bit confused, look like u're trying to make hashtag text place above the image but why u give image div z-index that make image place above hashtag. nvm if i was wrong

Comment: this messed up everything on the page :( position absolute on the .back class isnt working

Comment: I just want the bottom empty part of the div to dissapear so it doesnt split this split of the div causes the textbox to float above the div at the top :(

Comment: can u upload ur code to jsfiddle. it kinda hard to tell where was wrong

Comment: I can't the divs get loaded in from jquery/javascript and php from the twitter and instagram API i cant put this into jsfiddle sadly :(

Comment: actually u can use inspect element in chrome, copy all rendered html to jsf